# htaccess in conflict with ajax script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, .htaccess, conflict

I am using the pushstate event in js and therefore rewrote my htaccess in order to redirect every path in my url to the index.php:

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

that works just fine.. however I built an ajax script where I check if certain images are available.

```
function loadPicture(selector, file, errorf){

    $.ajax({url: file,type:'HEAD',error:function(){

        $(selector).attr('src', errorf);

        $('#notavailable').show();

    }, success:function(){

        $(selector).attr('src', file);

        if($('#notavailable').is(':visible')){

               $('#notavailable').hide();

        }

    }});

};
```

This script doesn't work anymore and I realized that it is because of the .htaccess.

Now I'm really not an expert in htaccess, I find it very hard to understand and could definitely need some help on this one. maybe someone can tell me how I can redirect every top-level / root path ( e.g. domain.com/somethingtoredirect ) to my index.php but make exceptions to certain or even every folder ( domain.com/thisfoldershouldnotberedirectedByHtAccess )

I think this would solve my problem as the images I'm checking are not stored high-level but in sub-folders..

Any help highly appreciated.

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exclude an image folder from your catch all rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dummy-image-folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```